# Prove this property of the same order of magnitude

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Show that if $f_i=O(g_i), \ i=1,..., n\ \ $  as $x\rightarrow 0$ and $|g_i|\leq|g|, \ i=1,...,n$
Then $$\sum^n_{i=1}a_if_i = O(g)$$ 
where $a_i$ are constants

I know that if $f=O(g)$ then there exists constants $C,\epsilon$ such that $|f(x)|<C|g(x)|$ whenever $0<|x|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $C_i$ such that $|f_i(x)|<C_i|g_i(x)|$ for $0<|x|<\epsilon$, then 
$$\left|\sum^n_{i=1}a_if_i\right|\le\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i||f_i|<\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|C_i|g_i|\le\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|C_i|g|=\left(\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|C_i\right)|g|,$$
which is what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f_{i}(x)=O(g_{i}(x))$ as $x \to 0$ by assumption implies that for every $i$ there is some $C_{i} > 0$ such that $|f_{i}| \leq C_{i}|g_{i}|$ on some neighborhood of $0$. Note that
$$
|\sum_{i}a_{i}f_{i}| \leq \sum_{i}|a_{i}||f_{i}| \leq \max_{i}C_{i}\sum_{i}|a_{i}||g_{i}| \leq (\max_{i}C_{i}\sum_{i}|a_{i}|)|g|
$$
on some neighborhood of $0$.
We are done.

Comment: Sorry - I was meant to put $x \rightarrow 0$ instead of $x \rightarrow \infty$. Have made edit in question